# laravel- is it possible to install a laravel project into existing laravel cpanel installation without SSH?

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, subdomain, cpanel

I've already installed the laravel setup into my cpanel using softaculous so I want to know if it's possible to not use SSH and composer to upload my project. And if so, then how?

Also, the installation is in a subdomain, the root for that subdomain is 'public_html/admin/'

Comment: You could do it with FTP maybe? Or a USB stick ^^

Comment: That worked, Thanks :)